# Alter or Create multiply stored procedures at once from multiply files in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large amount of stored procedures that I am updating often and then transferring to a duplicate database on another server. I have been opening each “storedproc.sql” file from within SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and then selecting Execute in the tool bar which will ether create or alter an existing stored procedure. I have been doing this for each stored procedure.

I am looking for a script (or another way) that will allow me to alter all of the stored procedures on the databases with ones that are located in a folder at one time. I am basically looking for a script that will do something similar to the pseudo-code like text below.

```
USE [DatabaseName]
UPDATE [StoredProcName]
   USING [directory\file\path\fileName.sql]
UPDATE [StoredProcNameN]
   USING [directory\file\path\fileNameN.sql
…
```

Not the cleanest pseudo-code but hopefully you understand the idea. I would even be willing to drop all of the stored procedures (based on name) and then create the same stored procedures again on the database. If you need more clarity don’t hesitate to comment, I thank you in advance.

To further explain:

I am changing every reporting stored procedure for an SSRS conversion project. Once the report is developed, I move the report and the stored procedure to a server. I then have to manually run (ALTER or CREATE) each stored procedure against the duplicated database so the database will now be able to support the report on the server. So far this has not been too much trouble, but I will eventually have 65 to 85 stored procedures; and if I have to add one dataset field to each one, then I will have to run each one manually to update the duplicate database.

What I want to be able to do is have a SQL script that says: For this database, ALTER/CREATE this named stored procedure and you can find that .sql text file with the details in this folder.

Comment: You can send an `alter` command from a C# program using `SqlCommand`.  Place the content of the .sql file in `CommandText` and specify `CommandType.Text`.  Then run `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: Is this a deployment issue, or simply an issue of copying from one DB to another?

Comment: @ulty4life This is really an issue of convenience or just simplifying the manual process of running (Create or Alter) each stored procedure against a duplicate database. I will edit my post to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that I use to move all stored procedures from one database to another:

```
DECLARE @SPBody nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @SPName nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @SPCursor CURSOR;
SET @SPCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ao.name, sm.definition
    FROM <SOURCE DATABASE>.sys.all_objects ao JOIN
         <SOURCE DATABASE>.sys.sql_modules sm
         ON sm.object_id = ao.object_id
    WHERE ao.type = 'P' and SCHEMA_NAME(ao.schema_id) = 'dbo'
    order by 1;

OPEN @SPCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @SPCursor INTO @SPName, @SPBody;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if exists(select * from <DESTINATION DATABASE>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines r where r.ROUTINE_NAME = @SPName)
    BEGIN
        SET @query = N'DROP PROCEDURE '+@SPName;
        exec <DESTINATION DATABASE>..sp_executesql @query;
    END;
    BEGIN TRY
        exec <DESTINATION DATABASE>..sp_executesql @SPBody;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        select @ErrMsg = 'Error creating '+@SPName+': "'+Error_Message()+'" ('+@SPBody+')';
        --exec sp__LogInfo @ProcName, @ErrMsg, @ProductionRunId;
    END CATCH;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @SPCursor INTO @SPName, @SPBody;
END;
```

You need to put in  and  as appropriate.

Comment: I think your statement is great but I was really hoping to go from a folder to the destination database. Also a loop would not work for me since I will need to call each one by name since the store procedures I need are a small subset of the hundreds of stored procedures in the database.

Comment: This is an example.  It is easy enough to add an "in ()" clause to the query in the cursor.  Also, I think you can use four-part naming to create sp's on a remote server -- although you would need to be careful that permissions are set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**[For Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)**

```
c:\>for %f in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <dbname> /E /i "%f"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend saving all your stored procedure script files starting with `if exists(...) drop procedure` followed by the `create procedure` section. Optionally include a `go` statement at the end depending on your needs.

You can then use a tool to concatenate all the files together into a single script file.

I use a custom tool for this that allows me to define dependency order, specify batch separators, script types, include folders, etc. Some text editors, such as [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) have this capability.

You can also use the [Microsoft Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx) to select batches of script files, and execute them against one or more database connections stored in the project. This is a good starting place that doesn't require any extra software, but can be a bit of a pain regarding adding and managing folders and files within the project.

Using a schema comparison tool such as [RedGate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare) can be useful to synchronize the schema and/or objects of two databases. I don't recommend using this as a  best practice deployment or "promote to production" tool though.